# how can implement case when in jet engin

Tags: php, wordpress, jet-engine

i made a table builder in jet engine.

one of columns of this table has Different conditions.

for example it may contain complete or failed or canceled condition. i want similar condition to sql `switch when` statment. that if it was complete show a label or it was canceled show another label.